# UITableViewCell being allocated but not displaying

Tags: ios, uitableview

Very strange problem. I have UITableViewController with a custom cell form the storyboard. For some reason the cell is not displaying in my TableView. I put some breakpoints in and some log messages and I can tell its getting data and I can see the cell has a memory address so its not nil. I just don't know what else to verify.

UPDATE for some reason the hidden property of the cell is being set to YES so I added cell.hidden = NO and it still doesn't appear.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *CellIdentifier;
if(indexPath.section == 0) {
    CellIdentifier = @"HeaderCell";
} else {
    CellIdentifier = @"ConnectedGoalCell";
}

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(indexPath.section == 0) {
 //Section 0 Formatting.....displays OK
} else {
 //This is the cell that doesn't appear in the tableView

    UILabel * nameLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    UILabel * dateLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:11];

    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    Goal * goal = [connectedGoals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    nameLabel.text = goal.name;
    dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:goal.goal_date];
    //Log said that cell HIDDEN was YES. Changed to no here but still no effect
     //<UITableViewCell: 0xa288e30; frame = (0 389; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xa292a80>
    cell.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"CELL TYPE : %@ AT %@", indexPath, CellIdentifier);
    //Logs::  CELL TYPE : <NSIndexPath 0xc3917d0> 2 indexes [1, 0] AT ConnectedGoalCell

    NSLog(@"%@", cell);
    //Logs::  CELL TYPE : <UITableViewCell: 0xc195ba0; frame = (0 389; 320 44); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xc171620>

}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Check your `ConnectedGoalCell`'s hidden property. It is being hidden.

Comment: Updated my question, thank you. Though obviously related that didn't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up having to create an new TableViewController in my Storyboard and setup my custom views again and everything works now One of my custom cells has about 20 buttons in it and luckily I was able to and paste them rather than having to tediously re-create them again. Very strange error but its working now!

Answer (score 0):

Read your log

> CELL TYPE : UITableViewCell: 0xc195ba0; frame = (0 389; 320 44); **hidden = YES;** autoresize = W;

I don't know why it's hidden, but it clearly should not be.

```
cell.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I don't know how it would have been set to Hidden I didn't do that in the Storyboard. It still has no effect. The cells are not displaying but it does appear that the space needed for the cells is. Could there be some other property that would make the cell invisible?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method (as opposed to the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method and then checking for `nil`), which means you must call one of the `register*:forCellReuseIdentifier` in, say, `viewDidLoad`. From the docs:

> Important: You must register a class or nib file using the
>   `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or
>   `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method before calling this
>   method.

Comment: Not in front my machine right but curious of this step is necessary since I have the cell defined in my storyboard